# Why isn't .build working in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, console

I'm working on building and testing associations with two models:  User, Posts. Essentially, a User `has_many` Posts, but a Post `belongs_to` only one User.

That said, I can't seem to get `User.first.posts.build` to work. I keep returning an error.

**As a side question, why is it that `User_id` is capitalized in the Post model? In most of the examples I've seen, that's not the case. When not capitalized, it runs this error:

```
Post.create(comment: "yolo molo tolo", user_id: 1)
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: user_id
```

**CODE**

(1) user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 40}
  has_many :posts 
end
```

(1) create_users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

(3) Post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :User
  validates :comment, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 30 }
end
```

(4) create_posts.rb

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :comment
      t.references :User, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**ERROR**

```
p3 = User.first.posts.new
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: user_id
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:47:in `rescue in _assign_attribute'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `_assign_attribute'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:29:in `block in assign_attributes'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `each'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `assign_attributes'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:178:in `initialize_attributes'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:251:in `block in build_record'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/core.rb:187:in `initialize'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:189:in `build_association'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:250:in `build_record'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:114:in `build'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:229:in `build'
    from (irb):19
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

Comment: If it returns "an error", then please, **post the error**. We're left guessing what might've gone wrong otherwise.

Comment: Where is `user_id` capitalized as `User_id`?

Comment: Does your database schema match your migration for comments? Is it possible you edited the migration and didn't rerun it?

Comment: Edited the question above to show where User_id is (in Post model), as well as the corresponding error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post model is missing user_id attribute, at least this is what your error means.

```
rails g migration add_user_to_posts user:belongs_to
rake db:migrate
```

You migration file shows you have user id in posts table, but it might be missing in db if you didn't run the migrations.

As a quick fix, **if you don't care abou your data in db**, I would run:

```
rake db:reset
```

Or

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought..I tried `rake db:reset`, but still getting the same error. I also tried `rails g migration add_user_to_posts..`. That doesn't seem to work either. I thought the Post model can have the user_id attribute through `rails g model Post comment:string User:references`

Comment: @KevinC `rails g model Post comment:string user:references`. It should be `user:references` not `User:references`

Comment: @Abednego, nice find, couldn't see that mistype last night. You are absolutely right, should be `t.references :user, index: true`.